# run .net core 6 application in ubuntu using wine

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, ubuntu

I need to run .net core 6 release in ubuntu with windows binaries because my application use windows dependency libraries, like ReportViewerCore.NETCore 
this linux service file:

```
[Unit]
Description= qashou
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/qashoulinux.programs-programming.com
ExecStart=sudo /usr/bin/wine64 ~/dotnet-6-windows-x86/dotnet.exe /var/www/qashoulinux.programs-programming.com/QashoaMediaApp.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=qashou
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

service status after do service start:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-94-39:~$ sudo systemctl status qashoulinux.service
● qashoulinux.service - qashou
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/qashoulinux.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) since Mon 2023-06-12 06:32:15 UTC; 856ms ago
    Process: 164447 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/wine64 ~/dotnet-6-windows-x86/dotnet.exe /var/www/qashoulinux.programs-programm>
   Main PID: 164447 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jun 12 06:32:15 ip-172-31-94-39 systemd[1]: qashoulinux.service: Succeeded.
```

but it got an error "502 Bad Gateway" when browse site in browser after start service 
note that I also used Nginx to reverse proxy:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/qashoulinux.programs-programming.com;
        server_name qashoulinux.programs-programming.com;
        location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

my ubuntu version: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 
wine version: wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)

Comment: Wine is primarily used to run certain .NET Framework applications on Linux or macOS, and is not recommended or supported for running ASP.NET Core applications.

Comment: The problems encountered now may be greatly affected by wine, [so I recommend you to read this document](https://medium.com/@JohGeoCoder/deploying-a-net-core-2-0-web-application-to-a-production-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04-using-nginx-683b7e831e6).